# Error running `recode` inside a container

Tags: fedora, container

I am running a Fedora container with:

```
podman run -it registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora:36
```

Inside this container, I first install `recode`:

```
[root@388e917ba8ce /]# sudo dnf install recode
```

Then, when trying to execute `recode`, I get this error:

```
[root@388e917ba8ce /]# touch deleteme.txt
[root@388e917ba8ce /]# recode windows1251..utf8 deleteme.txt
recode: /deleteme.txt failed: System detected problem in step `CP1251..UTF-8'
```

What could be causing this error?

Note that, when I run `recode` in my Fedora 36 system (without containers), I don't get any errors. Also, if I use an Ubuntu image, I don't get the error either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shared library */usr/lib64/gconv/CP1251.so* provides functionality for the encoding CP1251.

```
$ podman run -it registry.fedoraproject.org/fedora:36
[root@ea7d9d4dd16b /]# dnf provides /usr/lib64/gconv/CP1251.so
Fedora 36 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                           17 MB/s |  81 MB     00:04    
Fedora 36 openh264 (From Cisco) - x86_64                                                                                                                                    3.5 kB/s | 2.5 kB     00:00    
Fedora Modular 36 - x86_64                                                                                                                                                  2.0 MB/s | 2.4 MB     00:01    
Fedora 36 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                                                                 11 MB/s |  19 MB     00:01    
Fedora Modular 36 - x86_64 - Updates                                                                                                                                        1.8 MB/s | 2.2 MB     00:01    
glibc-gconv-extra-2.35-4.fc36.x86_64 : All iconv converter modules for glibc.
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/gconv/CP1251.so

glibc-gconv-extra-2.35-11.fc36.x86_64 : All iconv converter modules for glibc.
Repo        : updates
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/gconv/CP1251.so

[root@ea7d9d4dd16b /]#
```

The file */usr/lib64/gconv/CP1251.so* is provided by the RPM package **glibc-gconv-extra**.

After running `dnf install -y recode glibc-gconv-extra` it seems to work

```
[root@ea7d9d4dd16b /]# touch deleteme.txt
[root@ea7d9d4dd16b /]# recode windows1251..utf8 deleteme.txt
[root@ea7d9d4dd16b /]#
```